# Disabled activity still auto-populates

Tags: activities, automation

I've disabled certain activities that we do not want to keep track of (Record merged, for instance). Yet, when I merge a record, the activity is still automatically created. How can I prevent this from cluttering up our Activities tab in the future?

Comment: By default all activity get fetched, this query need to modify to restrict only enabled activities : https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Activity/BAO/Activity.php#L1642

i did submitted one PR couple of year back, but solution was implemented at php level https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/9812/files

Comment: There's some disagreement and there's been some discussion about what "disabled" choices should really mean and whether they should or shouldn't show in search results. For example https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/14240#issuecomment-496797810 and https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/19.

Answer (score 1):

Since that activity type is sort of a system type and is marked Reserved to discourage editing it, I don't think there is currently a way. Since you must have disabled it in the database outside the UI you might be ok with a workaround involving some coding. You might be able to write a little extension to use hook_post to delete activities of those types after they get created: https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_post/